# "The fi bug" A weird iOS 7 attributed text bug

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'm having a weird bug in iOS 7, I've called it "the fi bug".

Abstract:
The two characters "fi" are considered as one character.

Explanation:
I have created an UILabel with a word in it, as an attributed text.
I created a function that on click colors one character of the word in blue.
(i.e. first click it colors the first character, 
second click it colors from the first to the second…).

With iOS 6 simulator no problem at all, when we switch to iOS 7 simulator, everything is okey as long as the word does not contain "fi" on it. For instance when I write "finance", from the first click both f and i are colored in blue.

It does not depend on the 'fi' position, and seems to have the problem only with 'fi'.

code:

The UILabel:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wordLabel;`

The coloring function:

```
- (void) changeWordLabelWithWord:( NSString *)word to:(int) position{
NSMutableAttributedString *coloredText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:word];

[coloredText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.66 blue:0.96 alpha:1] range:NSMakeRange(0,position)];

_wordLabel.attributedText = coloredText;
}
```

Thank you for your help and insight ^^. 
Cheers !

Comment: Does it do this with all fonts?

Comment: You probably just need to disable ligatures.

Comment: yep, it was ligatures, thx.

Comment: How do you disable ligatures in app-wide?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the "ligature" attribute to zero on your `NSMutableAttributedString`.
 From the
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html):

> `NSLigatureAttributeName`
>    The value of this attribute is an NSNumber
>   object containing an integer. Ligatures cause specific character
>   combinations to be rendered using a single custom glyph that
>   corresponds to those characters. The value 0 indicates no ligatures.
>   The value 1 indicates the use of the default ligatures. The value 2
>   indicates the use of all ligatures. The default value for this
>   attribute is 1. (Value 2 is unsupported on iOS.)

With the default value `1`, the letters "fi" are rendered as one glyph.
Some fonts even have ligatures for three character sequences such as "ffl".

Comment: You can see a good example of the ffl ligature in the word "shuffle" here: http://www.apple.com/ipod-shuffle/

Comment: They get much longer than 3. :D Zapfino has a 7-character ligature for its own name. Arabic fonts often have ligatures that combine entire common phrases into a single glyph.

Answer (score 4):

iOS 7 adds a lot of typographical details. One of them are ligatures: the OS substitutes some character sequences by typographically better one glyph (character) variants.

Comment: Note that ligatures were available in iOS 6 as well. They just weren't as well supported in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can solve this. iOS 6.0+

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLigatureAttributeName value:@0 range:NSMakeRange(0,   label.text.length)];
[label.text setAttributedText:attributedString];
[attributedString release];
```