# NSAttributedString double "ff" counted as single "f" when using system font in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, uifont

I found a strange behaviour of NSAttributedString in iOS 7 with system font when using "ff" string. It's counted as single letter.
Here is result and code to test.

[image: aaaaaa]

[image: ffffff]

Is it bug or feature? How can I get rid of this without changing font?

If I change font to anything else letters are colored correctly.

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testText

- (void)testALetter
{
    NSDictionary *blackText = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                         NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:48]};

    NSDictionary *orangeText = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor],
                                           NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:48]};

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, 1);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"aaaaaa" attributes:blackText];
    [attributedString setAttributes:orangeText range:range];

    [self.testText setAttributedText:attributedString];
}

- (void)testFLetter
{
    NSDictionary *blackText = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:48]};

    NSDictionary *orangeText = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor orangeColor],
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:48]};

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, 1);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"ffffff" attributes:blackText];
    [attributedString setAttributes:orangeText range:range];

    [self.testText setAttributedText:attributedString];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The fi bug" A weird iOS 7 attributed text bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369439/the-fi-bug-a-weird-ios-7-attributed-text-bug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to be expected. This is a feature of the font called a [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature).

Check out `NSLigatureAttributeName` for options related to ligatures.

Comment: Thanks. Setting NSLigatureAttributeName : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] solved my problem.